# Bluetooth LE System.ObjectDisposedException The object has been closed

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, adafruit

I am trying to subscribe to the Notify feature of my Adafruit board in order to get some data. The device successfully connects to my c# application. However when I try to perform this operation:

```
await characteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);
```

I get a `System.ObjectDisposedException` The object has been closed. I have no idea why this happens...

The board is continuously writing to my app, would that be an issue? Can I only write a client characteristic descriptor only before the board starts writing? Or is the error caused by something else?

The board works perfectly fine with the Adafruit phone app.

```
var tmp = await characteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);                            
if (tmp == GattCommunicationStatus.Success) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Subscribed"); 
    characteristic.ValueChanged += characteristicValueChanged; 
    break; 
}                            
else 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(device.ConnectionStatus + " : " + tmp); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I get similar problems in my UWP code connecting to an O6 device. @GrooverFromHolland's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49822051/575530) did not work for me. What did work was earlier in the connecting code. Instead of something like this

```
var result = await DiscoveredBluetoothLEDevice.GetGattServicesAsync();
```

or this

```
var result = await DiscoveredBluetoothLEDevice.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(gattServiceGuid);
```

try this

```
var result = await DiscoveredBluetoothLEDevice.GetGattServicesAsync(BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
```

or this

```
var result = await DiscoveredBluetoothLEDevice.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(gattServiceGuid, BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
```

Answer (score 0):

On some windows version I had the same problem, don't know which version it was.
The solution was to make all BLE objects a field in my app so they are not affected by the garbage collector. it seems to be that things got disposed without reason.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception but in python while using BLE. The solution was simply to "forget device" in my bluetooth-settings, and run the program again.
Hope to save you the hours it took before i tried that!